# Problemas na inserção de dados do PHP para banco

Tags: php, sql

Segue abaixo o código em HTML

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTLM>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Formulário teste</title>
<!-- Biblioteca de font -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300italic,400italic,300,700,700italic&subset=latin,greek,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- font final -->
<!--    favicon    -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-48x48.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-48x48.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-160x160.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-160x160.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-160x160.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-160x160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-32x32x.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-160x160.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="http://www.leforte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/favicon-192x192.png">


<!--     Final favicon   -->
        <!--    css    -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="geral.css">
<!-- Final CSS -->
        </head>
    <body>

        <section class="container">
            <div class="resp"></div>
        <form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formulario">
            <ul id="progress">
            <li class="ativo">Dados Pessoais</li>
            <li>Atendimento</li>
            <li>Avalição</li>
            <li>Finalizar</li>
            </ul>

    <fieldset>
           <h2>Dados Pessoais</h2> 
        <h3>Preencha o campo abaixo</h3>
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Insira seu nome...">
         <input type="number" name="cpf" placeholder="Digite seu cpf...">
         <input type="tel" name="telefone" placeholder="(xx) xxxxx-xxxx">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail...">
        <input type="button" name="next1" class="next acao" value="Proximo">
    </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
           <h2>Atendimento</h2> 
        <p class="subtitulo">Informe se você recomendaria o Hospital LeForte a um parente ou amigo. Use uma nota de 0 à 5, sendo <b>0 "Nem um pouco provável"</b> e <b>5 "Altamente provável"</b>:</p>
            <select name=nota" class="servicos-utilizado">
            <option value="0">Selecione o quanto recomendaria...</option>
            <option value="Nem um pouco provavel">1- Nem um pouco provável</option>
             <option value="Pouco provavel">2- Pouco provável</option>       
             <option value="provavel">3- Provável</option>       
             <option value="muito provavel">4- Muito provável</option>       
             <option value="alto provavel">5- Altamente provável</option>       

        </select>
        <textarea name="nota_comentario" id="comentario" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Comente sua nota..."></textarea>
        <p class="pergunta-1">Qual é a sua relação com Hospital Leforte?</p>
        <select name="relacao_hospital" class="servicos-utilizado">
            <option value="0">Selecione sua relação...</option>
            <option value="paciente">Paciente</option>
            <option value="acompanhante">Acompanhante</option>
            <option value="medico">Médico</option>
        </select>

        <p class="pergunta-1">Qual serviço do Hospital você utlizou?</p>
        <select name="servicos" class="servicos-utilizado">
            <option value="0">Selecione o hospital</option>
            <option value="prontoatendendimento">Pronto Atendimento</option>
            <option value="Centro Cardiologia">Centro de Cardiologia</option>
            <option value="Centro de Oncologia">Centro de Oncologia</option>
            <option value="coleta de exames">Coleta de Exames</option>
            <option value="Radioterapia">Radioterapia</option>
            <option value="Internacao">Internação</option>
            <option value="Centro de Diagnostico">Centro de Diagnóstico</option>
            <option value="Check-up">Check-up</option>
            <option value="Nucelo Torax">Nucleo avançado do Tórax</option>
            <option value="Banco de Sangue">Banco de Sangue</option>
            <option value="Servico de Reabilitacao">Serviço de Reabilitação</option>
            <option value="Ambulatório">Ambulatório</option>
            <option value="Nucleo da Dor">Núcleo da Dor e distúrbios de movimento</option>
                </select>
            <input type="button" name="prev" class="prev acao" value="Anterior">
            <input type="button" name="next2" class="next acao" value="Proximo">

    </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
    <h2>Avalie-nos</h2> 
 <h3>Avalie os itens abaixo, conforme o seguinte critério:</h3>
       <ul class="avaliacao">
       <li>Muito abaixo das expectativas</li>
       <li>Abaixo das expectativas</li>
       <li>Expectativas Atendidas</li>
       <li>Acima das expectativas</li>
       <li>Muito acima das expectativas</li>
       <li>Não utilizou o serviço do hospital</li>
       </ul>
     <h4 class="subtitulo-1">Sua Avaliação</h4>
     <ul class="avaliacao-ass">
         <p>Assistêncial</p>
         <li>1</li>
         <li>2</li>
         <li>3</li>
         <li>4</li>
         <li>5</li>
         <li>6</li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="resposta-1">
         <p>1- As informações sobre o seu tratamento foram em tempo adequado e de forma compreensível?</p>
         <div class="estrelas">
                <input type="radio" id="vazio" name="avaliacao_1" value="" checked>

                <label for="estrela_um"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="estrela_um" name="avaliacao_1" value="1">

                <label for="estrela_dois"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="estrela_dois" name="avaliacao_1" value="2">

                <label for="estrela_tres"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="estrela_tres" name="avaliacao_1" value="3">

                <label for="estrela_quatro"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="estrela_quatro" name="avaliacao_1" value="4">

                <label for="estrela_cinco"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="estrela_cinco" name="avaliacao_1" value="5">


            </div>


     </ul>
     <ul class="resposta-1">
         <p>2- Suas necessidades individuais foram ouvidas e respeitadas pela equipe?</p>

         <div class="estrelas">
                <input type="radio" id="vazio" name="avaliacao_2" value="" checked>

                <label for="avaliacao_um"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_um" name="avaliacao_2" value="1">

                <label for="avaliacao_dois"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_dois" name="avaliacao_2" value="2">

                <label for="avaliacao_tres"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="estrela_tres" name="avaliacao_2" value="3">

                <label for="avaliacao_quatro"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_quatro" name="avaliacao_2" value="4">

                <label for="avaliacao_cinco"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_cinco" name="avaliacao_2" value="5">


            </div>


     </ul>
     <ul class="resposta-1">
         <p>3- A equipe mostrou-se alinhada/integrada em relação ao seu cuidado?</p>

         <div class="estrelas">
                <input type="radio" id="vazio" name="avaliacao_3" value="" checked>

                <label for="avaliacao_3_um"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_3_um" name="avaliacao_3" value="1">

                <label for="avaliacao_3_dois"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_3_dois" name="avaliacao_3" value="2">

                <label for="avaliacao_3_tres"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_3_tres" name="avaliacao_3" value="3">

                <label for="avaliacao_3_quatro"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_3_quatro" name="avaliacao_3" value="4">

                <label for="avaliacao_3_cinco"><i class="fa"></i></label>
                <input type="radio" id="avaliacao_3_cinco" name="avaliacao_3" value="5">


            </div>
     </ul>
 <input type="button" name="prev" class="prev acao" value="Anterior">
 <input type="button" name="next3" class="next acao" value="Proximo">
</fieldset>
            <fieldset>
           <h2>Finalizar</h2> 
        <h3>Você gotaria de receber informação do hospital por meio de veículos de comunicação?</h3>
                <select name="final_comunicar" class="servicos-utilizado">
                <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                <option value="sim">Sim, eu gostaria de receber...</option>
                <option value="nao">Não</option>



                </select>
        <p class="subtitulo">Boletins Informativos dos centros, núcleos e especialidades Utilize este espaço para deicar dúvidas, comentários ou sugestões:</p>
        <textarea name="sugestao" id="sugestao" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Deixe sua sugestão..."></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="prev" class="prev acao" value="Anterior">
        <input type="submit" name="next" class="acao" value="Enviar">
    </fieldset>
        </form>

        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    </body>



            </html>
```

Código JavaScript

```
$(function(){
   var atual_fs, next_fs, prev_fs;
    var formulario = $('form[name=formulario]');

    function next(elem){
       atual_fs = $(elem).parent();
        next_fs = $(elem).parent().next();


$('#progress li').eq($('fieldset').index(next_fs)).addClass('ativo');
        atual_fs.hide(800);
        next_fs.show(800);
    }

     $('.prev').click(function(){
       atual_fs = $(this).parent();
        prev_fs = $(this).parent().prev();


$('#progress li').eq($('fieldset').index(atual_fs)).removeClass('ativo');
        atual_fs.hide(800);
        prev_fs.show(800);
    });      
         $('input[name=next1]').click(function(){
             var array = formulario.serializeArray();
             if(array[0].value == '' || array[1].value == '' || array[2].value == '' || array[3].value == '' ){
                 $('.resp').html('<div class="container erros"><p>Preencha todos os campos corretamentes...</p></div>')
             }else{
                 $('.resp').html('');
                 next($(this));
             }
         });
    $('input[name=next2]').click(function () {
        var array = formulario.serializeArray();
        if (array[4].value == '' || array[5].value == '' || array[6].value == '' || array[7].value == '') {
            $('.resp').html('');
            next($(this));
        // } else {
        //     $('.resp').html('');
        //     next($(this));
        // }
    });
    $('input[name=next3]').click(function(){
            var array = formulario.serializeArray();
            if(array[8].value == '' || array[9].value == '' || array[10].value == '' ){
                $('.resp').html('<div class="container erros"><p>Ops!! Esqueceu de preencher algum campo...</p></div>')
            }else{
                $('.resp').html('');
                next($(this));
            }
        });
        $('input[type=submit]').click(function(evento){
        var array = formulario.serializeArray();
             if(array[11].value == '' || array[12].value == ''){
                 $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Ops! Esqueceu de preencher algum campo...</p></div>')

             }else{
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'cadastrar.php',
                    data: {cadastrar: 'sim', campos: array},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(){
                      $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Aguarde enquanto processamos...</p></div>')  
                    },
                    success: function(valor){
                     if(valor.erro == 'sim'){
                       $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>'+valor.getErro+'</p></div>');   

                         }else{
                             $('.resp').html('<div class="container ok"><img src="Logo-le-forte.png"><p>Agradecemos pela sua atenção!</p><a class="btn-voltar" href="index.html">Voltar</a></div>');

                     }
                    }
                });
             }
        evento.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Código PHP

```
  <?php
   include_once 'conexao.php';
        if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && $_POST['cadastrar'] == 'sim'):
            $novos_campos = array();
            $campos_post = $_POST['campos'];

        $respostas = array();
        foreach($campos_post as $indice => $valor){
            $novos_campos[$valor['name']] = $valor['value'];

        }if(!strstr($novos_campos['cpf']) <> 11){
            $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
            $respostas['getErro'] = 'Insira corretamente o cpf...';

        }elseif(!strlen($novos_campos['telefone']) <> 11){
            $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
            $respostas['getErro'] = 'Insira seu telefone corretamente...';

        }elseif(!strstr($novos_campos['email'], '@')){
            $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
            $respostas['getErro'] = 'E-mail invalido...';

        }else{
            $respostas['erro'] = 'nao';
            $inserir_banco = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO pesquisa_satisfacao SET nome = ?, cpf = ?, telefone = ?, email = ?, nota = ?, nota_comentario = ?, relacao_hospital = ?, servicos = ?, avaliacao_1 = ?, avaliacao_2 = ?, avaliacao_3 = ?, final_comunicar = ?, sugestao = ?");

                $array_sql = array(
                    $novos_campos['nome'],
                    $novos_campos['cpf'],
                    $novos_campos['telefone'],
                    $novos_campos['email'],
                    $novos_campos['nota'],
                    $novos_campos['nota_comentario'],
                    $novos_campos['relacao_hospital'],
                    $novos_campos['servicos'],
                    $novos_campos['avaliacao_1'],
                    $novos_campos['avaliacao_2'],
                    $novos_campos['avaliacao_3'],
                    $novos_campos['final_comunicar'],
                    $novos_campos['sugestao']

                );
            if($inserir_banco->execute($array_sql)){
                $respostas['msg'] = 'inserido corretamente...';
            }else{
                $respostas['erro'] = 'sim';
                $respostas['getErro'] = 'Por favor, tente mais tarde...';
            }
        }
            echo json_encode($respostas);


    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Qual problema? Retorna erro?

Comment: Um detalhe a corrigir: `<!DOCTYPE HTLM>`

Comment: ja ta corrigido, porem ainda persiste